# android - windowSoftInputMode issue

Tags: android, android-layout, window-soft-input-mode

How to I show the relative layout in the red area when soft input opened? I tried adjustPan and adjustResize input modes but did not happen. Any ideas?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your activity at manifest.xml.

Then create layout like below.

- As Parent, use `RelativeLayout`
- Put Inside 2 children(ScrollView and Bottom View)
- Bottom View `aligned to bottom`.
- ScrollView located `above` from Bottom View.

---

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        //scrollable content
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        //your bottom content
    </RelativeLayout >
</RelativeLayout>
```